# In JavaScript, why Number.MAX_VALUE | 0 is 0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitwise-operators

Being `|` and bitwise OR operation, shouldn't `Number.MAX_VALUE | 0` return just `Number.MAX_VALUE` instead of `0`?

And I tested with node.js and some browsers like Chrome, Safari and Firefox and the result is consistent.

Comment: `Number.MAX_VALUE > Math.pow(2, 32)` but javascript bitwise operators only operate on 32-bit ints. I guess the behavior is somewhat unpredictable. This is also why `Number.MAX_VALUE >> 0` etc. are equal to zero.

Comment: @soktinpk You should've left that as an answer.

Comment: @soktinpk if 0 is considered unpredictable, do you get predictable result for `1.7976931348623157e+308 | 0` in any language :P?

Comment: @Esailija That's a good question, and I'm not sure. I would have to look up how double precision floating-point numbers are represented.